# Login using javascript - setting element value doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

I need to submit a login here

https://global.138.com/en-gb/sportsbook

I use the following code to unhide the login form and fill in the values

```
document.getElementsByClassName("login-form-wrap")(0).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementsByName("username")(0).value= "foo"
document.getElementsByName("password")(0).value= "bar"
document.getElementById("submitlogin").Click
```

My issue is that the form says I have not filled in the username / password despite the values have been written to the form. The only way I can get it to work is to manually click inside the password box, then click the login button. It's like the page needs to detect a keystroke in order to detect the form is not empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried triggering a click on the input boxes before changing the input?

Comment: `(0)` should be `[0]`. Your code should be reporting that `getElementsByName` doesn't return a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about doing .focus() on the password field?